# How to edit a table row on same window in Eclipse RCP ?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have a table with many rows on a window. I want to edit a row. I have two options

1. I can open that row values in editor and then save.
2. I can open that row in the same window (beneath table), edit and save (same like above but on the same window where I am showing table).

I want to do second option.

any help (more details can be provided if required to understand the question)

Answer (score 1):

You can make columns editable using makeEditable

Refer this link :

http://www.ralfebert.de/blog/eclipsercp/tableviewerbuilder/

Comment: Thanks Snehal, I already have gone through that blog. Under the second option I have, in above question, I need to display widget (lable and text field for say name, city...) under the table itself. So half of the window would display table and remaining will display widget when I double click a row for edit. so when I double click a row, widget in the remaining window will get populated, then i will edit values and then save them again.